# Speed up zooming of D3 scatterplot in React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I want to make scatterplot of around 100.000 items using D3 that supports zooming with mousescroll. I managed to implement this in React. Unfortunately, the zooming interaction is very slow. Is there a way to make the zooming more smooth and instant?

My useEffect looks as follows

```
useEffect(() => {
        //setting up container width and height
        const w = width;
        const h = height;

        // create the result chart
        const resultChart = d3.select(resultChartRef.current)
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h)
            .style('margin-top', '10px');

        // Create the latent chart
        const latentChart = d3.select(latentChartRef.current)
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h)
            .style('margin-top', '10px');

            // d3.select(resultChartRef.current).selectAll().remove().exit()
        
        // Compute the scales of the two charts
        const resultScales = setScalesChart(dimRedData?.data?.result, w, h)
        const latentScales = setScalesChart(dimRedData?.data?.latent_space, w, h)

        if (currentZoomState) {
            const newXScale = currentZoomState.rescaleX(resultScales[0])
            const newYScale = currentZoomState.rescaleX(resultScales[1])
            resultScales[0].domain(newXScale.domain())
            resultScales[1].domain(newYScale.domain())
        };

        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(resultScales[0]).ticks(10)
        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(resultScales[0]).ticks(10)

        const gX = resultChart.append('g').call(xAxis).attr('transform', `translate(0, ${h})`);
        const gY = resultChart.append('g').call(yAxis);

        // TODO: styling properties http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/styles-in-d3js.html
        resultChart.selectAll('*').remove();
        resultChart.selectAll('circle')
            // select dataset
            .data(filterData(dimRedData?.data?.result))
            .enter()
            // Assign data value
            .append('circle')
                .attr('cx', d => resultScales[0](d[0]))
                .attr('cy', d => resultScales[1](d[1]))
                .attr('r', 2)
            // Add item colour
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                return dimRedData.data.colour[0][i]
            })
            // Set border width
            .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
            // Add border colour
            .style("stroke", "black");
            
        latentChart.selectAll()
            // select dataset
            .data(filterData(dimRedData?.data?.latent_space))
            .enter()
            // Assign data value
            .append('circle')
                .attr('cx', d => latentScales[0](d[0]))
                .attr('cy', d => latentScales[1](d[1]))
                .attr('r', 2)
            // Add item colour
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                return dimRedData.data.colour[0][i]
            })
            // Set border width
            .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
            // Add border colour
            .style("stroke", "black");

        // Zoom of the chart
        const zoomBehavior = d3.zoom()
            .extent([[0, 0],[w, h]])
            .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
            .translateExtent([[0,0], [w, h]])
            .on("zoom", (e) => {
                const zoomState = d3.zoomTransform(resultChart.node())
                setCurrentZoomState(zoomState);
                console.log("ZOOM!")
            });
        
        // Add zoom functionality to the result chart
        resultChart.call(zoomBehavior)
        
    }, [random, projectionFullScreen, currentZoomState]);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to speed it up or that I should change to a different approach. Or maybe even a different technology than D3.

Answer (score 0):

Possible things:

Not a react expert, but does zooming call that useEffect function each time? If so that's not good, because it's destroying and readding all 100,000 objects from scratch for the resultChart at least. You remove them all (resultChart.selectAll('*').remove();), then add them all in again through enter(). D3-wise you should be removing (via exit()) just existing objects with no corresponding data, adding objects (via enter()) where data has no corresponding object, and updating those where data and object both exist. For that to work you'll need a key function as a second argument on your .data(filterData(dimRedData?.data?.latent_space)) calls, usually it references an id field of the data objects.

Secondly, even with that done, that's an svg these 100,000 circles are getting added to, so it's going to be slow because zooming in and out by rescaling the svg involves the browser redrawing all these 100,000 objects it contains (it might have some smarts under the hood and not 'draw' ones that are outside the zoomed in view but still it has to calculate that)

I've made a d3-based scatterplot previously with a lot of points, and the only way I got it performant when zooming/panning was to plot the points to a canvas image and then zoom that in and out. But this means your circles will look jaggy/blurry depending on the antialiasing, so you may need to switch to square 'points' if you go down that route. I also needed to write my own code for interaction with the points

I guess in summary, unless this is for your own education or your restricted by other concerns, go and have a google for a react scatterplot library to see if someone else has already solved this ;-)